# Why cannot the type-specifier of a declaration of an object that is not a definition be a abstract class type

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```cpp
struct A{
  virtual void fun() = 0;
};
extern A a; //#1
void foo(A); //#2
int main(){}
```

The declarations at #1 and #2 are both complained as invalid declarations by GCC and Clang. The result is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/PqY651vjY).

However according to the current draft, it does not explicitly forbid this usage. What it states are just in the following
[[basic.def#5]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.def#5)

> In the **definition** of an object, the type of that object shall not be an incomplete type ([basic.types]), an abstract class type, or a (possibly multi-dimensional) array thereof.

In my example, the object `a` at #1 and the unnamed parameter at #2 are merely declarations rather than definitions, as per
[[basic.def#2]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.def#2)

> Each entity declared by a declaration is also defined by that declaration unless:
>
> > - it contains the extern specifier or a linkage-specification19 ([dcl.link]) and neither an initializer nor a function-body,
> > - it is a parameter-declaration in a function declarator that is not the declarator of a function-definition

The other place limits the usage of abstract class type related to this example is section [[dcl.fct.def]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.fct.def)

> The type of a parameter or the return type for a **function definition** shall not be a (possibly cv-qualified) class type that is incomplete or abstract within the function body unless the function is deleted

In other words, it does not limit the usage of abstract class type in a function declaration that is not a definition.

So, according to the behavior of the compilers, Could it say that, in the declaration of an object, the type of that object shall not be an abstract class type? If I miss some normative rule that limits the usage of abstract class type, please point it out.

Comment: Given both declarations are impossible to implement it's not unreasonable for the compiler to disallow them

Comment: The Standard says that any compiler must allow a definition of an object with an incomplete type, but it does not specify whether it should allow a declaration or not. Since given such a declaration, it will not be able to link whether we define it or not, it makes sense that the compiler will act wisely and alert you about this problem.

Comment: @AlanBirtles If we do not odr-use the entity, it is not necessary to implement.

Comment: If you aren't going to use an entity why declare it?

Comment: @Orielno That's just a reasonable behavior but not a normative rule. If we do not odr-use the entity, it is not necessary to have the definition.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Why cannot I use such an entity to hide the name of some type that I do not hope the user to use it?(just for example a usage). The tag is [language-lawyer], what I want to talk is whether the rule is reasonable.

Comment: P0929R2 is supported in GCC11, see https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html. For clang, I've only found http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Clang-support-for-C-20-P0929-Checking-for-abstract-class-types-td4070093.html

Comment: @LanguageLawyer According to P0929R2. Does it mean `#1` and `#2` should be accepted since we do not call the function or define the function, and `#1` is not a definition of an object.

Comment: GCC11 accepts it.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Ah, thanks. I saw [that](https://godbolt.org/z/q51x8cP53)